# ECharts Apache: Bar chart - add horizontal level line

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, echarts

I use EChart.JS in my project.

I need to add an accent as a horizontal level line for each bar. And also to add a default value.

```
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById("sleep_graph"), null, { renderer: 'svg' });

   var option;

   option = {
       xAxis: {
           type: 'category',
           data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
           show: false
       },
       yAxis: {
           type: 'value',
           splitLine: {
               show: false
           }
       },
       series: [
           {
               data: [
                   {
                       value: @sleepGraph.DeepSleepDurationValue,
                        itemStyle: {
                           color: new echarts.graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
                               { offset: 0.2, color: '@sleepGraph.DeepSleepDurationGraphColor' },
                               { offset: 1, color: 'white' }
                           ]),
                           opacity: 0.8
                       },
                       label: {
                           show: true,
                           position: 'top',
                           color: '@sleepGraph.DeepSleepDurationGraphColor',
                           fontWeight: 'bold'
                       },
                       labelLine: {
                           show: true,
                           lineStyle: {
                               type: 'solid',
                               color: 'black',
                               width: 55,
                           }
                       }
                   },
                   {
                       value: @sleepGraph.SleepDurationValue,
                       itemStyle: {
                           color: new echarts.graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
                               { offset: 0.2, color: '@sleepGraph.SleepDurationGraphColor' },
                               { offset: 1, color: 'white' }
                           ]),
                           opacity: 0.8
                       },
                       label: {
                           show: true,
                           position: 'top',
                           color: '@sleepGraph.SleepDurationGraphColor',
                           fontWeight: 'bold'
                       }
                   },
                   {
                       value: @sleepGraph.LightSleepDurationValue,
                       itemStyle: {
                           color: new echarts.graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
                               { offset: 0.2, color: '@sleepGraph.LightSleepDurationGraphColor' },
                               { offset: 1, color: 'white' }
                           ]),
                           opacity: 0.8
                       },
                       label: {
                           show: true,
                           position: 'top',
                           color: '@sleepGraph.LightSleepDurationGraphColor',
                           fontWeight: 'bold'
                       }
                   },
                   {
                      value: @sleepGraph.RemSleepDurationValue,
                      itemStyle: {
                           color: new echarts.graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
                               { offset: 0.2, color: '@sleepGraph.RemSleepDurationGraphColor' },
                               { offset: 1, color: 'white' }
                           ]),
                           opacity: 0.8
                       },
                       label: {
                           show: true,
                           position: 'top',
                           color: '@sleepGraph.RemSleepDurationGraphColor',
                           fontWeight: 'bold'
                       }
                   }

               ],
               type: 'bar',
               barWidth: 35,
               showBackground: true,
               backgroundStyle: {
                   color: 'rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.2)'
               }
           }
       ]
   };

   option && myChart.setOption(option);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [ESChart](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#%2Fsearch%2FmarkLine), there's only [chart line has markline property](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.markLine) (But it only provide single markline). So there's no way to add horizontal level line to bar chart in ESChart.js

But you can try [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/), it provides [adding marker at the chart](http://jsfiddle.net/ufme91hy/).

```
      marker: {
        symbol: 'c-rect',
        lineColor: 'red',
        lineWidth:3,
        radius: 10
      },
      type: 'scatter',
```

Edit:
[ApexChart](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/column-charts/column-with-markers/)

It's MIT licence and it support showing markers on chart

https://jsfiddle.net/s3xfqw6p/

Comment: Do you know MIT licensed libraries with the same functionality?

Comment: @MichaelKostiuchenko yep, i edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I failed to see your image but from your description, I think it's possible to do so with an extra bar series stacking on it. See examples at: https://www.makeapie.com/editor.html?c=xwigwFaytn and https://www.makeapie.com/editor.html?c=xD58D_iJlS .